# typedef myFLOAT Float64 / BigFloat

Tags: julia

in C(++) I can do in a header file myFLOAT.h

```
typedef myFLOAT double;
// typedef myFLOAT BigFloat; // with the correct lib
```

Then I can write code based on the type myFLOAT 
and switch very easily for the code between double and BigFloat 
by just uncomment/comment the corresponding line 
in the header file.

How do I do the same in Julia?

I tried

```
abstract type myFLOAT <: Float64 end
#abstract type myFLOAT <: BigFloat end
```

but I get

```
ERROR: invalid subtyping in definition of myFLOAT
```

I add the following comment after the answer from @clbieganek

My simulation code generally looks like

```
init = initSimulation(args);
result = doSimulation(init);
Plotting(result);
```

I agree that I can/should use AbstractFloat "everywhere" in doSimulation().
But with

```
const myFLOAT = Float64     # thanks
```

I want to guarantee that every myFLOAT in    'struct init'    is a Float64 or BigFloat depending on the use case. This way 'doSimulation(init)' will choose
the correct Float type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Julia, concrete types cannot be sub-typed. `Float64` and `BigFloat` are both concrete types, which is why you are getting the invalid sub-typing error. The direct translation of what you are trying to do is to create a type alias:

```
const MyType = Float64
```

However, the Julian approach is to define your types and methods using the most generic types possible. In your case, you could use `AbstractFloat`. Then your code will work with both `Float64` and `BigFloat`. For example,

```
julia> struct A
           x::AbstractFloat
       end

julia> function foo(a::A, x::AbstractFloat)
           return a.x + x
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a1 = A(4.5)
A(4.5)

julia> foo(a1, 5.2)
9.7

julia> a2 = A(BigFloat(4.5))
A(4.5)

julia> foo(a2, BigFloat(5.2))
9.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

The Julia type hierarchy for numbers can be [viewed here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Types#Type_hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the where syntax for the functions, and use syntax like T, then, for either:

```
julia> function f(a::T) where T <: Number
       ret = zeros(T, 5, 5)
       ret
   end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = 1.0
1.0

julia> f(x)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> y = BigFloat(1.0)
1.0

julia> f(y)
5×5 Array{BigFloat,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

julia>
```

Comment: Note that declaring `T <: Number` allows `T` to be `Complex`. I usually declare `T <: Real`.